# Unable to receive inbound XML sent via cURL on remote API server

Tags: php, api, curl

I am tasked with building an API to receive inbound XML data. On my client, I have this code.

```
 $url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
 $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request PartnerID="asasdsadsa" Type="TrackSearch"> <TrackSearch> <Title>love</Title>    <Tags> <MainGenre>Blues</MainGenre> </Tags> <Page Number="1" Size="20"/> </TrackSearch> </Request>';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml=".$payload );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 $request = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

On my remote server, I have this code

```
 function TransmitRx()
 {
    $xml = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    file_put_contents("newStandard/".rand(100,500)."received.xml", $xml);
 }

 //Listen for inbound data 
 TransmitRx()
```

If I open up the server endpoint URL, there is an empty file saved. I don't know why. But when I run the client-side script. I get nothing. No errors. Nothing.

I have looked at several of the pages here and every one of them has a similar cURL statement to send data.

Why am I not receiving any post data at the API endpoint?

I have been unsuccessful at any information via the WWW.

**UPDATE**

Final Code that works:

```
function get_url($request_url, $payload)
{
        $headers = [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
            "Content-type: text/xml",
            "Content-length: " . strlen($payload),
            "Connection: close",

        ];

        $data = ['xml' => $payload];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));;

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            print curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        return $response;
}

$request_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts';
$response = get_url($request_url, $payload);
```

I wish I knew for sure what caused it to start working. I was reading this page last.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

Comment: Try taking out the "xml=" in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and just send $payload

Comment: Thank for your response but that did not work is the reason that the "xml=" in there.

Comment: Usually when you see "foo=bar", it's because you're trying to send things in a form encoded way.  If there was some intermediate device trying to parse the content, then that syntax could confuse it. The other thing to check is whether or not there is any redirection. For example, let's say you post to a URL ending in "/service/” and the web server tries to redirect you to "/service" or vice versa. Any redirection could result in your payload being lost and php://input being empty. You can try using Fiddler or Postman to emulate the exact same POST and see if it redirects you.

Comment: there is not redirect on my remote server. It is just a recever.php file. I have a previous iteration on this same server but in that one, I am using ajax to send the data stream. Now that the data stream is bigger. I need another way to send the xml data to the server.

Comment: The data stream you showed in your example is pretty small. How big is the actual stream you are testing with?

Comment: I just re-read your post. I thought you said that when you test your client code, it creates an empty file on the server. Upon re-reading it, it sounds like you opened the receiver script in your browser, which created an empty file. But when you run the client code, it doesn't seem to trigger the remote receiver script at all. If that's true, have you tried checking curl errors? Another thing to test is to TEMPORARILY disable SSL certificate validation. You don't specify any certificate bundle or files to use so maybe the client script is not successfully getting past the SSL handshake.

Comment: I did receive a ssl certificate error but in my reading it said to do this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

Comment: I a researching what is the magic behind the cURL post. How does it work? So, I can have the correct code on the remote server-side.

Comment: Datastream is 5kb.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if adding the lines I suggested to disable certification / peer validation enabled the process to work, then that just means the remote server is using an SSL certificate that is not trusted by cURL.

Those lines are NOT the final fix. You never want to disable SSL validation in a real environment. I only suggested you temporarily disable them to see if that was truly the problem. If you leave them disabled, then you are leaving your code vulnerable to man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.

The correct fix is usually to point cURL at an updated CA bundle. The official cURL website graciously provides these here:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

The process is that you download the CA bundle file and put it somewhere where your script can find it, and then add this curl option:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "full path to the CA bundle file.pem");
```

If the remote server's certificate came from any of the major CA vendors out there, this should be all you need to do.

If the remote server's certificate is self-signed or something then you might need to download the specific CA certificate and any supporting intermediate CA certificates and tell cURL to find them.

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it did not work. I downloaded the pem file and placed it in the same directory as the class file and give it the $pem = (__dir__)."ca.pem". Still got the same error unable to validate SSL. There was one opinion that stated there is no need to validate if consuming an external SSL.

Comment: That opinion is wrong. As I stated, if you disable validation, you are stripping away one of the most important security features of SSL, making you vulnerable to MITM.

Comment: If that suggestion didn't work, then either you have a self-signed CA or you got the code wrong. Make sure you are turning on VERBOSE logging for cURL so you can verify that it is loading your CA bundle correctly and you can also see some more context for the error.